# Loading Select2 Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a q-tip that I am applying Select2 in. I have a q-tip in each row in a table which varies in length. The content of the q-tip along with the select2 is loaded in through an ajax call. Here is the information loaded in through ajax:

```
<script> 
$('.editCommType').select2();  
</script>

<div>
<select class="editCommType" style="width:170px;" name="typeoptions">
            <option <% If LogType = "Inhouse Project" Then response.Write("selected")     End if%> value=2> Inhouse Project </option>
            <option <% If LogType = "Non-Picking Hours" Then response.Write("selected") End if%> value=4> Non-Picking Hours </option>
            <option <% If LogType = "Other ($)" Then response.Write("selected") End if%> value=0> Other ($) </option>
        </select>
</div>
```

When I click to bring up the first q-tip my select2 works fine without any error. However, any other q-tips that I click on after that select2 is not applied and I get an error saying Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_autogen67.

Here is my q-tip function:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.editComm', function(event) {
    var EmpKey = $(this).attr('EmpKey')
    var key = $(this).attr('key')
    var comm = $(this).attr('comm')
    var type = $(this).attr('type')
    var amount = $(this).attr('amount')
    $(this).qtip({
        overwrite:false,
        position: {
            effect: false,
            my: "top right",
            at: "bottom center",
            adjust:{x: 8}

        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded',
            tip: {
                corner: 'top right', 
                mimic: 'top center',
                width: 15,
                height: 10
            }
        },
        content: {
            text: 'Loading...',
            ajax: {
                    url: '/peeps/ManagePeeps/AJAX/HRDashEdit.asp',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { 
                            key:$(this).attr('key'), 
                            FormType:9,
                            EmpKey:$(this).attr('EmpKey'),
                            comm:$(this).attr('comm'),
                            type:$(this).attr('type'),
                            amount:$(this).attr('amount'),
                            PayPeriod:$(this).attr('PayPeriod')
                    }



            }
        },show: {
            event: event.type,
            ready: true
        },
        hide:{
            event: 'unfocus'
        }
    }, event);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your selector is a class, every time you call it, it tries to apply `select2` to every element with that class on the page. When you try to create the 2nd `select2`, the function tries call `select2` on the first select, which is already a `select2`, so it throws that error.

Since `select2` adds the class `select2-offscreen` to an element after it is created, you could change:

```
$('.editCommType').select2();
```

to

```
$('.editCommType:not(.select2-offscreen)').select2();
```

-Edit: This method does not work, see comments for solution.

Comment: Is there somewhere in my q-tip function that I should put this code? I put it into my ajax page and I still get the error.

Comment: Come to think of it, that might not work. I'm unsure after looking at the documentation. Try implementing it this way instead: `$('.editCommType:not(.select2Created)').addClass("select2Created").select2();`